# How to call content of a parsed (NSXMLParser) xml from another class? Code review?

Tags: ios, nsxmlparser

I am trying to give the contents of a parsed xml file  in the  view Controller. How can i do it when the content of the node string is.

xml file is like this:

```
<XML>
 <Data> 
    <ID_Number>8</ID_Number>
    <Date> 13.12.2009</Date>
    <Time>  17:50:00</Time>
    <Temperature> 37.2  </Temperature>
    <Speed>34.2</Speed>
    <Direction>90.4</Direction>
    <AirPressure>1040.3</AirPressure>
 </Data>
</XML>
```

My Parser   in .h file

```
@interface Parser : NSObject 


@property ( nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *mutableTemperatureValue;
@property ( nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *mutableWindDirection;
@property ( nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *mutableWindSpeed;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *mutableAirPressure;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *mutableAcquiredDate;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableString *mutableAcquiredTime;

-(void)parserStart;
@end
```

m.file :

```
-(void)parserStart
{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myWebServiceXMLUrl];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:data ];

NSString *xmlCheck = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"xmlCheck =%@", xmlCheck);

[xmlParser setDelegate:self];

[xmlParser parse];

}
```

Delegate methods  in .m file like:
didStart...

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Date"] ){
    self.mutableAcquiredDate = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    return;
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Time"]){
    self.mutableAcquiredTime = [[NSMutableString alloc]init]; 
    return;
}

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Temperature"]){
    self.mutableTemperatureValue = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    return;
}
.
.
.
```

foundCharacters:

```
[self.mutableTemperatureValue appendString:string];
[self.mutableWindSpeed appendString:string];
[self.mutableWindDirection appendString:string];
[self.mutableAirPressure appendString:string];
[self.mutableAcquiredDate appendString:string];
[self.mutableAcquiredTime appendString:string];
```

and didEnd
    .
    .
    .

```
 if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Date"]){
    NSLog(@"mutableAcquiredDate : %@", self.mutableAcquiredDate); // this gives the right data
    return;

}
```

in viewController .h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelWindSpeed;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelTemperatur;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelAirPressure;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelUpdateDateTime;
```

in viewController .m file

```
 //  Create Parser object and start parsing 
self.parser = [[Parser alloc]init];
[self.parser parserStart];

// Assigning the values from Parser Class to labels

// Date and Time
self.labelUpdateDateTime.text = self.parser.mutableAcquiredDate ;
NSLog(@"---------:%@", self.labelUpdateDateTime.text);// This gives all the contents of the xml nodes why?

 // Temperatur
myStartTemperatureValue = [self.parser.mutableTemperatureValue floatValue];
labelTemperatur.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", myStartTemperatureValue];// This     works also correct.
```

How can I reach   only the content of the Date node from viewController without having all the contents of the nodes listed.
Thanks...

Comment: If you use dictionary then quite easilty by `objectForKey:` and/or `valueForKeyPath:`

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to put them in an `NSMutableDictionary` since you could access them by their original tags. In your header for the parser, declare

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *dic;
BOOL parsing;
NSString *title;
NSString *cont;
```

and use the delegates like this

```
@synthesize dic;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
parsing = YES;
title = elementName;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
if (parsing) {
NSMutableString *str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1000];
[str1 appendString:string];
if ([dic valueForKey:title] == nil) {
    [dic setValue:str1 forKey:title];
}
else{
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *delete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if ([[dic objectForKey:title] isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]){
        for (NSString *str in [dic objectForKey:title]){
            [arr addObject:str];
        }
        [arr addObject:str1];
        for (NSString *s in arr) {
            if ([s isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
                [delete addObject:s];
            }
        }
        [arr removeObjectsInArray:delete];
        [dic setObject:arr forKey:title];
    }
    else{
        [arr addObject:[dic objectForKey:title]];
        [arr addObject:str1];
        for (NSString *s in arr) {
            if ([s isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
                [delete addObject:s];
            }
        }
        [arr removeObjectsInArray:delete];
        [dic setObject:arr forKey:title];
    }
}
}
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
if (parsing) {
parsing = NO;
}
}
```

This inserts them all into the `NSMutableDictionary *dic` according to their tags in the XML, and access certain objects, like the date, by calling this from a different class

```
[parser.dic objectForKey:@"Date"];
```

This also creates an array for a file that has multiple nodes with the same name