# Swift: What's the best way to have multiple NSXMLPasrser Delegates?

Tags: xml, swift

I am working on a project that is consuming a REST based API with XML output.  We have multiple objects that have standard format XML responses to queries.  For the sake of this question, let's assume we have Users and Devices.  User responses are always formatted the same, but they are different than device responses.  I would like to write custom **didStartElement** and **didEndElement** functions for each query type.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  I already tried creating a new class as an NSXMLParserDelegate but I am getting errors when I try to make it the delegate of my parser.  I could be doing this wrong.  I appreciate your assistance.

The following code is in the actual ViewController Page

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]){
    //Do this for user response
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?){
    //Do this for user response
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String){
    //Do this for user response
}

func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser){
    //Do this for user response
}
```

I added a new class page like this:

```
import UIKit

class Device_Parser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate {

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]){
        //Do this for device response
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?){
        //Do this for device response
    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String){
        //Do this for device response
    }

    func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser){
        //Do this for device response
    }


}
```

One the ViewController page I tried to call the new parser class like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
    parser.delegate = Device_Parser
    parser.parse()


}
```

On the parser.delegate = Device_Parser I am getting the following error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Device_Parser.Type' to type 'NSXMLParserDelegate?'

Is it possible to have multiple parser delegates that parse differently?  What am I doing wrong?  I can set the parser.delegate = self, but I don't know how to set the delegate to another set of **didStartElement** and **didEndElement** functions.  Sorry if this is rookie mistake, still learning Swift.

**NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION** I specifically marked this as a Swift question and the proposed duplicate question did not help me.  Ole Begemann's solution was exactly what I was looking for and fixed my issue.

Comment: *" I could be doing this wrong"* — perhaps, but how could we possibly know?

Comment: What would you like to know jtbandes?  I will add code...

Comment: Added code, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call content of a parsed (NSXMLParser) xml from another class? Code review?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710808/how-to-call-content-of-a-parsed-nsxmlparser-xml-from-another-class-code-revie)

Comment: You are doing it wrong. Create a method in Device_Parser say parserStart and right below code into it let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!) parser.delegate = Device_Parser parser.parse() will come in Device_Parser. And from ViewController you have to allocate this class and call obj.parserStart()

Comment: This is not a duplicate and the references question did not solve my problem.  My issue is specific to swift and I don't know enough about objective-c to be able to convert it. I will try Ole's proposed solution later today and update the thread at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
parser.delegate = Device_Parser
```

you are trying to assign a *class* as the parser's delegate. You need to create an *instance* of the class and make that the delegate. Something like this:

```
let parser = NSXMLParser(data: data!)
let deviceParser = Device_Parser()
parser.delegate = deviceParser
parser.parse()
```

As Arun Gupta mentioned, it might be a good idea to move part of that code into the `Device_Parser` class itself.